# Sending notification to 25k+ users causing problem on backend

Tags: php, firebase, webserver

There is currently 25k+ users we have in database. All users are subscribed to a common topic `All`.

I have two directories inside `public_html`. First is for API built in codeigniter. This API is used to provide data for all adnroid and iOS devices.

Second directory is for admin panel built in Laravel. We use it to upload data and also to send notification to firebase topics.

Both API and Admin Panel share same database.

> If we send notification to topics which is not subscribed by much
>   users, there is no issue. 
>  But If I send notificaiton to a topic
>   which has much users It causes problems on our backend. 
>  The API
>   stops responding, or sometimes takes too long to respond.
>   Sometimes also admin panel stops responding too.

I am so confused because all the things are handled by firebase. I just make one API call.
Can anyone explain what's causing the problem?
Or any possible reason?
*Update*

```
use Kreait\Firebase\Messaging;
use Illuminate/Support/Http/Request;

trait UserTrait {

public function notify(Request $request, Messaging $messaging) {

        $message_hi = array(

            "notification_type" => $notification_type,

            "notification_title" => $notification_title_hi,

            "icon_image" => $icon_image,

            "notification_description" => $request->notificationText_hi,

            "image_url" => $request->image_url,

        );

        $message = array(

            "notification_type" => $notification_type,

            "notification_title" => $notification_title,

            "icon_image" => $icon_image,

            "notification_description" => $request->notificationText,

            "image_url" => $request->image_url,

        );
 $commodityIdArray = $request->cId

//to send all
if($request->notification_type == 1) {
 $messaging->sendAll([
                ['topic' => 'All', 'data' => $message],
                ['topic' => 'All_hi', 'data' => $message_hi],
            ]);
 } else {
   //to send to a fourite topic subscribed by some users
    //Prepare Condition for both hindi and english users
             $topic_condition = "";
             $topic_condition_hi = "";
             foreach($commodityIdArray as $topic) {
                 $topic_condition .="'".$topic."' in topics && ";
                 $topic_condition_hi.="'".$topic."_hi' in topics &&";

             }

            //send notification to hindi and english topics
             $messaging->sendAll([
                ['condition' => substr($topic_condition, 0, -3), 'data' => 
                    $message],
                ['condition' => substr($topic_condition_hi, 0, -3), 'data' => 
                    $message_hi],
                ]);


 }

}
```

Comment: How do you actually make the call to the Firebase API, and how do you determine which topic to send the message to form your application? A request to the Firebase API should always take the same amount of time when sending to a topic - the Firebase API accepts a message and then processes the delivery asynchronously.

Comment: @jeromegamez I am using a package https://github.com/kreait/firebase-php 
I don't have to determine anything. I have subscribed all the users to a common topic `All` for english users and `All_hi` for hindi users. I just use this method from the package `$messaging->sendAll([ ])`

Comment: @jeromegamez You can also have look  on this issue https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-java/issues/238 . I want to know the reason why this is happening. By the way, I am not using Java, I am using PHP.

Comment: I'm the creator of the package you're using ^^. The sendAll method might not be the correct one to send the messages to a topic - could you please update your post to show us the code that you wrote to send the message(s), please?

Comment: @jeromegamez I updated the question and added codes. By the way, I knew you are the creator of the package. ;)

Comment: Could you try replacing the call to `sendAll()` with two separate calls to `send()` for each message? This would cause a different API endpoint to be used, perhaps it would make a difference. But I‘m just guessing :/

Comment: @jeromegamez Yes

Comment: @jeromegamez This package is so bad when it comes to error handling, and there is no documentation for this.
I am so confused I just make one call and storing it in db why it is being non responsive. Also why you?

Comment: @jeromegamez I need to know how this package behaves on cURL calls?

Comment: If you need to debug API requests, you can do this by following https://firebase-php.readthedocs.io/en/stable/troubleshooting.html#debugging-api-requests - in addition, you can configure the underlying Guzzle HTTP client to your liking by following https://firebase-php.readthedocs.io/en/stable/setup.html#http-client-options-and-middlewares

Comment: As I said here and in the GitHub issue you opened: you could start by using the appropriate methods to send multiple messages at once. The SDK doesn't "behave" on cURL requests, it uses Guzzle as the HTTP handler, and Guzzle decides if it uses cURL or another transport layer. The SDK is not responsible for the environment it's running in.

Comment: As for the "bad error handling" and "no documentation", please point me to where you're missing information and I'll try to improve it (and happily accept pull requests with improvements)

Comment: @jeromegamez Can I run this asynchronously? It would be easier if I run them in background and return response from Api? There are  asynchronously cURL methods and as you said This package uses cURL. That might be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

**Use Queue**

You have to use a Queue which set your process in queue and when one process completes, the second one starts

you can also set number of retries of your process

Comment: What to queue? I am just making one API call to firebase.